# Dividing the plane into regions of equal mass based on a density function

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

**Given a "density" scalar field in the plane, how can I divide the plane into nice (low moment of inertia) regions so that each region contains a similar amount of "mass"?**

That's not the best description of what my actual problem is, but it's the most concise phrasing I could think of.

---

I have a large map of a fictional world for use in a game. I have a pretty good idea of approximately how far one could walk in a day from any given point on this map, and this varies greatly based on the terrain etc. I would like to represent this information by dividing the map into regions, so that one day of walking could take you from any region to any of its neighboring regions. It doesn't have to be perfect, but it should be significantly better than simply dividing the map into a hexagonal grid (which is what many games do).

I had the idea that I could create a gray-scale image with the same dimensions as the map, where each pixel's color value represents how quickly one can travel through the pixel in the same place on the map. Well-maintained roads would be encoded as white pixels, and insurmountable cliffs would be encoded as black, or something like that.

My question is this: does anyone have an idea of how to use such a gray-scale image (the "density" scalar field) to generate my "grid" from the previous paragraph (regions of similar "mass")?

I've thought about using the gray-scale image as a discrete probability distribution, from which I can generate a bunch of coordinates, and then use some sort of clustering algorithm to create the regions, but a) the clustering algorithms would have to create clusters of a similar size, I think, for that idea to work, which I don't think they usually do, and b) I barely have any idea if any of that even makes sense, as I'm way out of my comfort zone here.

Sorry if this doesn't belong here, my idea has always been to solve it programatically somehow, so this seemed the most sensible place to ask.

---

***UPDATE:*** Just thought I'd share the results I've gotten so far, trying out the second approach suggested by @samgak - recursively subdividing regions into boxes of similar mass, finding the center of mass of each region, and creating a voronoi diagram from those.

[image: Map divided into regions of similar mass]

I'll keep tweaking, and maybe try to find a way to make it less grid-like (like in the upper right corner), but this worked way better than I expected!

Comment: How important is "same size"?  That is, do you want to work to get the regions to come out exactly even, or would it be possibly preferable if it looked random and there were factor of 2 differences in the weight?

Comment: Also is it "from one region to another" or "from any point in a region to another"?  That is, can a region include a tall mountain even though actually getting to/from the mountain top takes more than a day of travel?

Comment: Regarding your first question: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Visually, the regions would have different sizes. The most important feature of a solution would be that travel from any region to any adjacent region is as close to the ideal value as it could be. I suppose it would be more important to me to minimize the most extreme outliers, than to simply improve the average. Not sure if that answers anything.

Comment: As for the second question: I have yet to find a good way to handle **very** difficult terrain. I suppose I sort of think of the shortest path between the centers of the regions as the relevant measure, but I'm not sure that's how I should be thinking.

Comment: It may not be very helpful, but I think this a version of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facility_location_problem where the locations are the state capitals and the boundaries of the states for the Voronoi diagram produced by those capitals.

Comment: I think you're right, mcdowella. I can't say for sure I'll be able to use that information right not, but it helps me personally to know the class of problem I have been working on, if only to remember it in case I encounter a similar problem later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of rough ideas:

You might be able to repurpose a [color-quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization) algorithm, which partitions color-space into regions with roughly the same number of pixels in them. You would have to do some kind of funny mapping where the darker the pixel in your map, the greater the number of pixels of a color corresponding to that pixel's location you create in a temporary image. Then you quantize that image into x number of colors and use their color values as co-ordinates for the centers of the regions in your map, and you could then create a [voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) from these points to define your region boundaries.

Another approach (which is similar to how some color quantization algorithms work under the hood anyway) could be to recursively subdivide regions of your map into axis-aligned boxes by taking each rectangular region and choosing the optimal splitting line (x or y) and position to create 2 smaller rectangles of similar "mass". You would end up with a power of 2 count of rectangular regions, and you could get rid of the blockiness by taking the centre of mass of each rectangle (not simply the center of the bounding box) and creating a voronoi diagram from all the centre-points. This isn't guaranteed to create regions of exactly equal mass, but they should be roughly equal. The algorithm could be improved by allowing recursive splitting along lines of arbitrary orientation (or maybe a finite number of 8, 16, 32 etc possible orientations) but of course that makes it more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Building upon @samgak's solution, if you don't want the grid-like structure, you can just add a small random perturbation to your centers. You can see below for example the difference I obtain:

without perturbation
[image: Pure centroids]

adding some random perturbation
[image: Perturbated centroids]