# Given generating points of a voronoi diagram; compute the vertices of it

Tags: algorithm, graphics, computational-geometry, voronoi

Let $p_i$ be the i-th point in 2-dimensional space generating a voronoi diagram. That means, every point $x$ in a Voronoi region $V_i$ satisfies

$|x-p_i|<|x-p_j|,i \neq j$

and $|x-p_i|=|x-p_j|,i \neq j$ on its boundary. The boundary is a graph with vertices and edges. Now I am interested on the location of the vertices that span the boundary (edges) of the Voronoi diagram.

Which algorithms exist for computing the vertex positions of a Voronoi diagram when I pick a $p_i$?

I know that I can search of the nearest neighbor generators of the $p_i$ and then use the circumcircle property; but how can I find the locations of the nearest neighbors as efficient as possible (meaning that I have found a Delaunay triangulation)?

Note that I am interested how I find the coordinate vector $(r_x,r_y)$ of the vertex (where three edges of the boundary meet) lying on the boundary that separates Voronoi regions. Any hints?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dividing the plane into regions of equal mass based on a density function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973555/dividing-the-plane-into-regions-of-equal-mass-based-on-a-density-function)

Comment: You're going to have to create some kind of data structure to support efficient point queries.  Why not make that data structure a Delaunay triangulation?

Comment: @MattTimmermans: it there any efficient way to locate a point in a Delaunay triangulation ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust OP wants to pick one of the input points, not an arbitrary point.   But to answer your question, yes, you just find the closest point with a K-D tree, R-tree, or similar and then check the triangles with its Delaunay neighbors.

Comment: @MattTimmermans: this is not exploiting the structure of the triangulation, so why using it at all ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Precomputing the Delaunay triangulation is for the OP's question, not *your* question :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust One very efficient way to locate a point in a Delaunay triangulation is by using a "walk" algorithm such as Lawson's Stochastic Walk. A good Delaunay library will include one.  There are lots of papers about Delaunay walk algorithms on the web. I wrote an explanation that is (I hope) pretty straightforward on page 28 of http://gwlucastrig.github.io/Tinfour/doc/TinfourAlgorithmsAndDataElements.pdf (see 2.2.8.4 Vertex Location)

Comment: @GaryLucas: if I recall correctly, a walk is average case O(√n), which is not optimal.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: your recollection is correct... The time-complexity of a walk is O(√n) in the general case. From a practical point-of-view, if your code is doing a large number of walks in a regular pattern (such as producing a grid), it can start each walk from where it finished the previous one.  In that special (though quite common) case, the adjacent point is close to the previous query, the walks stay short, and the average case is O(k).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the optimal solution is complicated.

You can construct the diagram with the Fortune's or Guibas & Stolfi's algorithm, which take O(N Log N) time and O(N) space. (As the Voronoi diagram and Delaunay triangulations are duals of each other, you can construct one or the other interchangeably.)

But the representation of the Voronoi diagram is not suitable for efficient location of an arbitrary point. So you have to convert it to a structure such as a Trapezoidal Map, which allows efficient point location queries in time O(Log N). Unfortunately, I have never seen an explicit algorithm that performs this transformation in the frame of Voronoi diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

Computing the Voronoi region in the plane is equivalent to computing the intersections of `n` half-planes - the half-planes defined by the bisector lines between the point `p_i` and every other point `p_j`.
However, this problem is equivalent (by duality) to computing the convex hull of `n` points in the plane (see [Chapter 30.5 on Arrangements](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Emichas/chap30-fin2.pdf) in the Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry).
Computing the convex hull of a set of points in the plane [has a known lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Lower_bound_on_computational_complexity) of `\Omega(n log n)`.

Computing the Delaunay triangulation takes only `O(n log n)` time.
Therefore, preprocessing the input into a Delaunay triangulation, as @matt-timmermans and @yves-daoust suggested, does not have a real overhead and is probably the best choice for most applications.

Once the Delaunay triangulation is computed, each query (the construction of the region boundary)
takes only `O(1 + k)` time, where `k` is the output size i.e., the number of vertices/edges on the Voronoi region boundary.
Note that `k` itself can be `\Omega(n)`, for example if `n-1` points are placed more-or-less on a circle and `p_i` is near its center.

While the worst-case algorithm is `\Omega(n log n)` and therefore not better than computing the Delaunay triangulation,
there is also an option for an output-sensitive algorithm that takes `O(n*k)` (depending on the size of the output Voronoi region).

Finding a single vertex on the boundary of the Voronoi region is equivalent to the result of a linear programming problem
(see Chapter 4 of [Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540779735)).

In particular, Megiddo's algorithm or its randomized version (Chapter 4.4 of the book above) run in `O(n)` linear time.
Once the first vertex, with its two generating lines, are found, one can find the next vertex by intersecting the remaining lines with the generatng line.
The closest intersection point is the next Voronoi vertex, and the closest intersecting line then becomes the next line to intersect with.
The process terminates when the first vertex is reached again.
All in all, each iteration takes `O(n)` and there are `k` iterations, so this algorithm takes a total of `O(n*k)`.